# Python function that counts number of lower case and upper case letters in a string

Tags: python

I am an absolute beginner, and I can't figure out why my code is not giving the expected outcome. I wanna write a function that calculates the number of lower and upper case letters in a given string. Example follows.

String : 'Hello Mr. Rogers, how are you this fine Tuesday?'
Expected Output :

No. of Upper case characters : 4

No. of Lower case Characters : 33

```
def up_low(s):
    upper_case_count = 0
    lower_case_count = 0

    split_s = s.split()

    for word in split_s:

        if word.islower() == False:
            upper_case_count +=1
            lower_case_count += len(word) - 1
        elif word.islower() == True:
            letter_count = len(word)
            lower_case_count += letter_count

    print(f'No. of Upper case characters is {upper_case_count}')
    print(f'No. of Lower case characters is {lower_case_count}')
```

If I run the function I wrote on the previous example, I get 4 and 36, instead of 33. Also, I'm pretty sure that what I wrote is not correct anyways because it only works if words in the string have only one capital letter, but I don't know how to fix it in order to have it count the uppercase letters no matter how many there are in the word

Comment: `s.split()` splits a _sentence_ to words, not a word to characters.

Comment: Also note that punctuation counts as characters; you're including `.,?` in the total, which is why you're getting 36 instead of 33

Answer (score 4):

For the lower and upper case count respectively (string is in `a`)

```
sum(i.islower() for i in a)
sum(i.isupper() for i in a)
```

And with credit to suggestion from @Jean-François Fabre, using `map`.

```
sum(map(str.islower,a))
sum(map(str.isupper,a))
```

Full program

```
print(f"The number of lower case characters is {sum(map(str.islower,a))}")
print(f"The number of upper case characters is {sum(map(str.isupper,a))}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def up_low(s):
    upper_case_count = 0
    lower_case_count = 0

    for letter in s:
        #If letter is uppercase, add 1 to upper count
        if letter.isupper():
            upper_case_count +=1

        #If letter is lowercase, add 1 to upper count
        if letter.islower() == True:
            lower_case_count +=1

        #All other characters, such as punctuation and questions, will be ignored.


    print('No. of Upper case characters is {}'.format(upper_case_count))
    print('No. of Upper case characters is {}'.format(lower_case_count))


s = 'Hello Mr. Rogers, how are you this fine Tuesday?'

up_low(s)
```

Output:

```
No. of Upper case characters is 4
No. of Upper case characters is 33
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def up_low(s):
    upper_case_count = 0
    lower_case_count = 0

    for char in s:
        if char.isupper():
            upper_case_count += 1
        elif char.islower():
            lower_case_count += 1

    print(f'No. of Upper case characters is {upper_case_count}')
    print(f'No. of Lower case characters is {lower_case_count}')
```